# Is it possible to make C preprocessor to call external scripts

Tags: c-preprocessor

Is it possible to make C preprocessor(`cpp`) to call external scripts? For example:

```
$ ./snmp 
C3750
$ cat test
switch model:
#script snmp /* starts an external bash script named snmp */
$ cpp -P < test


switch model:
C3750
$
```

Comment: No, it isn't. (And how would that work, anyway? How could you possibly distribute the source code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to write a Makefile or other automated build system which invokes scripts; you can feed the information from the script into the source file using the `-D` option (for gcc/clang/etc.) or equivalent. But the preprocessor itself is independent of any operating system interface other than reading files for `#include` directives.

For example, you could compile your program with something like:

```
gcc -DSWITCH_MODEL="$(./snmp)" test.c -o test
```

(Of course, you would probably want other options). That would result in the preprocessor variable `SWITCH_MODEL` being `#define`'d as `C3750` (assuming that's the output of the `snmp` script).